# how to remove the last airplane of a runway and add it to the terminal?

Tags: java

I have a menu option that looks like this

```
 public static void airControlmenu() {
    System.out.println("\n1: Next plane is cleared for  takeoff");
    System.out.println("2: Last plane on runway 1 must return to terminal.");
    System.out.println("3: Last plane on runway 2 must return to terminal.");
  }
```

When the user chooses 2 or 3 the last airplane on the runway goes to the terminal. Runway1, runway2 and terminal are deque methods this is what I have so far:

```
    static Deque<Airplane> runway1 = new ArrayDeque<>();
static Deque<Airplane> runway2 = new ArrayDeque<>();
static Deque<Airplane> terminal = new ArrayDeque<>();

static Airplane plane1 = new Airplane("AA", 4992);
static Airplane plane2 = new Airplane("DL", 1345);
static Airplane plane3 = new Airplane("AA", 4531);
static Airplane plane4 = new Airplane("DL", 9873);
static Airplane plane5 = new Airplane("AA", 3414);
static Airplane plane6 = new Airplane("DL", 2366);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testCase4();

    while (!runway1.isEmpty() || !runway2.isEmpty()) {
        printRunway();
        airControlmenu();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String AirChoice = input.next();
        int AirportNum = Integer.parseInt(AirChoice);
        if (AirportNum == 1 ) {

             runway1.pollFirst();
             runway2.pollFirst();


        } else if (AirportNum == 2) {
           runway1.pollLast();

        }else if (AirportNum == 3) {
            runway2.removeLast();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\n\nThere are no more planes on runways 1 and 2.");
        }
```

I'm just having a little trouble removing the plane and adding it to the terminal. its probably a simple fix.

Comment: Why are you removing the terminal from runway1 if the AirportNum == 2?

Comment: I was actually trying to get the last airplane on runway 1 to go to the terminal

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing your program to crash, but you're removing from runway1 without checking to see if it's empty or not in the first if statement. Same thing with runway2 in the second else if.

Comment: And can you explain what you're trying to do in the second else if statement? It seems as though you are trying to find and remove an entire ArrayDeque Object in runway1 as opposed to adding it to the terminal

Comment: Ok so I fixed why it crashed I just need assistance on removing a plane from the runway and adding it to the terminal

Comment: Just a quick comment on replacing .remove() with .pollFirst(), with .remove() the code would break because the runway is empty and .remove() throws an error when you try to remove from an empty ArrayDeque. .pollFirst() doesn't break the code because it returns null, but unless you have some condition checking if it removed an element, you as the developer, and anyone using the program, won't know if the plane was successfully removed from the from the runway or not.

Comment: I know I can't say thanks or whatever. but how would I alternate between two arraydeques after each menu? like the first time a user chooses option 1 it will take off an airplane in runway1. The second time they choose option 1 I want it to take off an airplane in runway2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say removing a plane from the runway and adding it to the terminal, I'm assuming you want to take it out of the runway ArrayDeque and add it to the terminal ArrayDeque. In your edit, you changed the code from runway1.remove to runway1.pollFirst().  That method returns the object that you removed, so you want to store that in some variable, like this:

```
Airplane plane = runway1.pollLast();
```

What this will do is remove the plane from runway1 and store it in a variable, so that you can then add it to the terminal with:

```
terminal.add(plane);
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to add the plane to the beginning or end of the terminal, .add() adds it to the front, .addLast() will add it to the back. That should take care of what you wanted to do. Alternatively, you could reduce it to just one line of code if you wanted to, like this:

```
terminal.add(runway1.pollLast());
```

which does the same thing as the previous 2 lines, however you just won't have the plane stored in a variable, in case you needed to use that instance again (it doesn't seem like you do, but I could be mistaken).

Comment: I know I can't say thanks or whatever. but how would I alternater between two arraydeques after each menu? like the first time a user chooses option 1 it will take off an airplane in runway1. The second time they choose option 1 I want it to take off an airplane in runway2

Comment: Sorry about the late response, just got back to my computer. If you are only working with 2 runways, you could have a variable that switches between 1 and 2, and use it in conjunction with some if statements. So the variable could start off by being assigned 1, and when option 1 is selected, the variable now has a value of 2. When option 1 is selected again, the variable is now assigned 1 again. You would need an if-else statement, if variable == 1, runway1.poll; variable = 2; else, runway2.poll, variable =1;